# Double click contentEditable highlight issue on IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have an editable span. Whenever someone clicks on the span, it's calling an onclick function, and it's setting contentEditable to True and also setting up a couple of styling. Then I'm using onblur to save the value into the database using an ajax call. When I'm running this on chrome and doing a double-click, it's selecting the particular value. For Ex: if there is a value "mm/dd/yyyy" and if I double click on yyyy then it's highlighting it, and I'm able to change it. But this func. is not working on Internet explorer. On IE, when I do a double click, it's able to select but not taking any input from my keyboard key. Again when I do double click, then it's working fine. I know it's hard to explain, but I want this to work the same in IE. Below is my onclick function.

```
function makeElementEditable(span){
  span.style.border = "1px solid black";
  span.style.fontSize  ="15px";
  span.style.padding = "5px";
  span.contentEditable = true;
  }
});
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try this code. This is how I used to give my IE support after trying to kill myself thinking about how to fix every IE related bugs. => `if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) { alert("Your browser is killing your PC. Delete internet explorer and use Firefox or Chrome or Safari."); setTimeout(function() { window.close() } ); }`

Comment: Haha... Very funny, but I really need to find the solution.

Comment: Good luck brother. :) 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested in IE and reproduced the issue. I think it's due to different behavior in different browsers. It's by design.

You could try to use `<input>` instead of `<span>` as a workaround in IE. To make it as much as possible like `<span>`, you could set the `border` of the `<input>` to `none`:

```js
function makeElementEditable(span) {
  span.style.border = "1px solid black";
  span.style.fontSize = "15px";
  span.style.padding = "5px";
  span.style.width = "90px";
  span.contentEditable = true;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" onclick="makeElementEditable(this)" value="mm/dd/yyyy" style="border:none" />
</div>
```